# Map memory from alloc_page to the calling process address space

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a Linux device driver that allocates physical memory/pages. I have a single ioctl, which any application can call, which simply allocates a physical page and maps it to process memory using `vm_insert_pfn`.

I have already allocated a contiguous VMA based on the total number of pages required by the application. I am using `alloc_page()` to allocate a physical page.

What I want to know is, if the physical page allocated by `alloc_page()` is counted against the process making the IOCTL or if it is simply a physical page that belongs to the driver even after mapping it to pre-allocated VMA. If not how can I achieve this?

I am using flags like `GFP_MOVABLE|GFP_HIGHUSER`.

Comment: Counted where? Do you mean pss/rss counters ?

Comment: counted means is it allocated in calling process's address space or does it gets allocated in kernel's physical address space?

Comment: Everything is allocated as page in buddy allocator, but you can map this page as you wish. You can't allocate in address space - it is about mappings